# Updating FGLRX driver fails & deactivates FGLRX driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, fglrx

I have an ATI/AMD graphics card in my computer. However, every time I try to install the post-release updates, it always fails ***and*** deactivates the graphics driver.

I've pasted the last few messages following the `ldconfig deferred processing now taking place` message from the installation log from `/var/log/jockey.log` below; if you're interested, I have pasted the full output [here](http://pastehtml.com/view/ca8434rpl.txt).

```
WARNING: /sys/module/fglrx_updates/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind fglrx_updates driver
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: XorgDriverHandler(%s, %s).enabled(): No X.org driver set, not checking
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: XorgDriverHandler(%s, %s).enabled(): No X.org driver set, not checking
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: XorgDriverHandler(%s, %s).enabled(): No X.org driver set, not checking
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: XorgDriverHandler(%s, %s).enabled(): No X.org driver set, not checking
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
DEBUG: XorgDriverHandler(%s, %s).enabled(): No X.org driver set, not checking
```

What's going on? Is `ldconfig` corrupted, or has the driver package just not been properly installed, despite reporting to the "Additional Drivers" panel that it is?